# ¿Como llamo una función de JavaScript en una etiqueta de input?

Tags: javascript, html

Cordial saludo. Tengo un problema y es el siguiente:

Quiero llamar una función de `JavaScript` que solo permite escribir números en un campo de `input`, pero no sé como hacerlo.

De antemano agradezco sus respuestas.

```
function justNumbers(e){
var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))
return true;

return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
}

var pais = document.getElementById('pais');
var telf = document.getElementById('telf');

pais.onchange = function(e) {
    telf.value = this.value;
    if((this.value).trim() != '') {
        telf.disabled = false;
    } else {
        telf.disabled = true;
    }
}
telf.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var nums_v = this.value.match(/\d+/g);
    if (nums_v != null) {
        this.value = '+'+((nums_v).toString().replace(/\,/, ''));
    } else {
        this.value = pais.value;
    }
        this.value = this.value.replace(/(\+\d{2})(\d)/, '$1 $2');
}
```

Quiero que se ejecute esta función en este `input`:

```
<label">Documento</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="documento" value="<?php 
if(isset($documento)) echo $documento; ?>" required>
```

Comment: Colocando onkeypress = "tuFuncion()" en la etiqueta input, haría que al presionar una tecla, se active tu función.

Comment: Le agregas ``id="documento"`` el input, y con jQuery seria: $("#documento").change(nombreDeLaFuncionAEjecutar()); Esto lo que hace es que, una vez que escribas en el input, y salgas del mismo (ya sea apretando la tecla tab o haciendo click fuera del input) se ejecute la funcion ``nombreDeLaFuncionAEjecutar()``

Comment: on keyup tambien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidentemente el usar un control numérico es la mejor opción, pero si deseas hacerlo con JavaScript (para cuestiones propias de tu implementación) creo que en tu código está la respuesta.

Has conectado anteriormente los controles con id's "pais" y "telf" con los eventos `onchange` y `keyup` respectivamente.

Para conectar este control podrías hacer lo siguiente:

`document.getElementsByName("documento")[0].addEventListener('change', justNumbers);`

Por cuestiones de reutilización de código te recomiendo que setees una clase específica en el control, para que puedas usarla en otros controles

```
document.querySelector('.numeric').addEventListener('change', justNumbers);
```

Así podrás colocar más elementos `input` con la clase "numeric" y controlarlos a todos con tu función.

Otra sugerencia es que uses el evento `keyup` para controlar el backspace y el pegado desde el portapapeles.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que querés hacer es ejecutar la función cada vez que escribas una letra en el `input`,usas la función `onchange=MyFunction()`, si lo que querés es ejecutar la función luego de apretar un botón `onclick=MyFunction()` el `onclick` va en la etiqueta del botón.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `input` de tipo `number` que te restringe el uso de números únicamente y es nativo de `html`:

```html
<label for="documento">Documento</label>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="documento" value="<?php 
if(isset($documento)) echo $documento; ?>" required>
```